# Which side up do caged bearings go in?

Tags: fork, headset, bearings

Replacing fork on bike but messed up and didn't keep all the pieces in order as I took the old fork off. Which direction do the caged bearings go? What side of bearings face the cup and which side to the cone? Thanks

Comment: Look at where the two races are - they will be at an angle.   if you put the bearings in and the bearing balls aren't aimed at the race, then its upside down, flip it and recheck.

Comment: https://youtu.be/61Gygv82DAM

Comment: @DanielRHicks if you can summarize that video, it seems like a reasonable answer.

Comment: DanielRHicks that was a very helpful video! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When replacing your headset bearings you must have the non caged side ( the balls ) facing into the cup that sits on your frame , this means that when the headset is compressed together the ball bearings can roll on the cup allowing the handlebars to turn.

Answer (score 2):

There are variations depending on the design.

Here is a picture with two common configurations.
[image]

Answer (score -4):

[image: bearings; sealed and loose]

The key to orienting caged (loose) bearings correctly is to observe that the races do not work together in pairs, but in *quadruples*.

If it were just a pair (sealed bearings; top left of the figure), the load of the rider (red arrow) would be supported at the axle (black arrow) *vertically*.

Just one bearing (top left) would *in theory* be enough. You still need a pair of sealed bearings (top left and right) to avoid sway.

The load applied in loose bearings (two red arrows; bottom of the figure) arises from a combination of the rider weight as well as the clamping force. The two forces are counter-acted by the axle (two black arrows; bottom of the figure). (Hence, incidentally, the axle holds compression forces.)

Comparing the two figures also clarifies why the clamping force matters so much with loose bearings. It can be neither so high to lock the bearings, nor so low for them to be loose. It has to be ["just right"](https://youtu.be/Uxi7wTRGfZM?t=190).

Here I used the term "vertically" on the assumption these are hub bearings, but the same idea applies for the headset if you look at it sideways. The same also applies for the bottom bracket, except that the load will alternate between left and right.

Comment: Slight clarification: the diagrams do not depict sealed vs loose bearings, but rather radial contact vs angular contact ones.

Comment: @MaplePanda Yes, despite the many words and the figure, the answer is quite succinct. Many details are left "as an exercise to the reader", which I'm sure you can easily imagine.

Comment: Well, but which way do the caged bearings go then? That was the question. Which side to the cone and which side to the cup?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава 1/2 I have so far watched Calvin Jones's demonstrations for how to adjust the FD and RD 5 times (easily, each). My chain dropped inside the smaller chainring on my last ride. Yet I am STILL unable to just go and retune the FD. I need to read again my notes or re-watch. I do not even have enough understanding to guess whether it's cable elongation, slipping at the pinch bolt, or something else.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава 2/2 The moral of the story is that you can show people a superb algorithm to solve a problem ("give them a fish," so to speak) and they'll always come back. But you can explain WHY everything needs to be done in a certain way ("teach them to fish"), and they'll never need you. Once they understand the problems surrounding cycling, the solutions—as in this case—are usually quite trivial. Here one simply needs to make sure the cage will not rub on either of the two races.

Comment: *"Here one simply needs to make sure the cage will not rub on either of the two races."* While that does nicely follow from the video linked by Daniel in the comments, I do not see how that in any way follows from this answer, which mostly presents the theory of load bearing by ball bearings.

Comment: Or I see but it is very well hidden and very hard to see. At least for me. One has to understand that the while the two rop cuts cannot be the same bearing cut at two locations (the orientation is wrong), it is how one should interpret the bottom figure. Perhaps. Maybe not. The text in the answer is really hard to understand und will not help a clueless person too much.

Comment: I am also not quite seeing how this answers the question? Also, the top figure appears to be a cross section of one bearing. The text describes each side as one bearing. This ... seems off? Bearings are toruses.